# Kotlin null checks(!!) when nullability is already checked

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a question about Kotlin and its null checks warnings.

Let's assume I created an object called "user" with some attribute like name, surname, etc etc. The following code is an example:

```
if(user != null) {
    val name = user!!.name
    val surname = user.surname
    val phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber
} else 
    // Something else
```

Why, even if I checked that user is not null, Kotlin wants me to use !! the first time I call user? It cannot be null at this point.

I know that I can use the following block but I don't understand this behavior.

```
user?.let{
    // Block when user is not null
}?:run{
    // Block when user is null
}
```

Comment: That is just a warning, because compiler is not going to evaluate whole code snippet. It is just evaluating the line with declaration of variable.

Comment: When I run your code above, I get a "Unnecessary non-null assertion" warning on the second line. It also doesn't make sense: either you have to always check for nullability (so getting a surname also would need a `!!`), or just once (at the `if`). Please check if the code you posted is correct.

Comment: How is your `user` field declared? When I try this code snippet I have to do non-null cast on every single line, if compiler lets you off with 1 cast only that's weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a reason for that behavior. Basically, it's because the compiler can't ensure that the value of `user` doesn't become null after the `if` check.

This behavior is only applicable for `var user`, not for `val user`. So for example,

```
val user: User? = null;
if (user != null) {
  // user not null
  val name = user.name // won't show any errors
}
```

```
var user: User? = null;
if (user != null) {
  // user might be null
  // Since the value can be changed at any point inside the if block (or from another thread).
  val name = user.name // will show an error
}
```

`let` allows you to ensure immutability even for `var` variables. `let` creates a new final value separate from the original variable.

```
var user: User? = null
user?.let {
  //it == final non null user
  //If you try to access 'user' directly here, it will show error message,
  //since only 'it' is assured to be non null, 'user' is still volatile.
  val name = it.name // won't show any errors
  val surname = user.surname // will show an error
}
```